# docker - how to overcome Proxy settings on the server

Tags: docker, docker-network

My dockerfile doesn't contain any manually added network configuration. Also its using windows image as a base.

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`

It runs on a server where I am not able to modify anything, but that server has proxy settings and it doesn't `telnet` the URL `http://timestamp.comodoca.com` which is used by signtool.exe tool for signing build package.
I cannot telnet directly from the server as well.

But I am interested if I am able to have access to the internet within the docker container, without modifying the networking configuration on the server itself?

Thank you